# How to detect changes in the contents of a file, using Regex and Chokidar

Tags: javascript, node.js, chokidar

I would like to run a JS function when a specific section of a file changes. The contents that are being watched should be selected by Regex.

As far as I have seen, libraries like Chokidar can only detect changes to a file directly and do not provide information about the contents of the file before and after the changes.

Comment: Watch for file changes, read file content when changed, apply your search regex on the file content, profit.

Comment: What info are you looking to capture from the events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a slightly adjusted version of [Prashant Pokhriyal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75251859/11090915).

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const chokidar = require('chokidar');

const watchForFileContentChanges = (path, regex, callback) => {
    const regexFileContents = new Map();

    const registerFileContentMatches = (filePath) => {
        const currentFileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
        const currentFileMatches = currentFileContent.match(regex);
        if (currentFileMatches === null) return;
        regexFileContents.set(filePath, currentFileMatches);
    }

    const handleContentChanges = (filePath) => {
        const previousFileMatches = regexFileContents.get(filePath);
        const hasFileBeenReadBefore = previousFileMatches !== undefined;

        const currentFileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
        const currentFileMatches = currentFileContent.match(regex);

        if (hasFileBeenReadBefore === false) {
            regexFileContents.set(filePath, currentFileMatches);
            if (currentFileMatches === null) return;
            callback();
            return;
        }

        const haveFileMatchesChanged = JSON.stringify(previousFileMatches) !== JSON.stringify(currentFileMatches);

        if (haveFileMatchesChanged === false) return;

        regexFileContents.set(filePath, currentFileMatches);
        callback();
    }

    const handleFileRemoval = (filePath) => {
        regexFileContents.delete(filePath);
    }

    chokidar.watch(path)
        .on('add', registerFileContentMatches)
        .on('change', handleContentChanges)
        .on('unlink', handleFileRemoval);
}

watchForFileContentChanges('output/*.txt', /foo/g, () => {
    console.log('foo changed');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into all the data available on chokidar events? It's built right on top of node's `fs` package, so it should have everything available in the native `fs.stats` package.

**Chokidar example**

```
// 'add', 'addDir' and 'change' events also receive stat() results as second
// argument when available: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats
watcher.on('change', function(path, stats) {
  if (stats) console.log('File', path, 'changed size to', stats.size);
});
```

Here's what is provided on the native **`fs.stats`**:

```
Stats {
  dev: 2114,
  ino: 48064969,
  mode: 33188,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 85,
  gid: 100,
  rdev: 0,
  size: 527,
  blksize: 4096,
  blocks: 8,
  atimeMs: 1318289051000.1,
  mtimeMs: 1318289051000.1,
  ctimeMs: 1318289051000.1,
  birthtimeMs: 1318289051000.1,
  atime: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 23:24:11 GMT,
  mtime: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 23:24:11 GMT,
  ctime: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 23:24:11 GMT,
  birthtime: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 23:24:11 GMT }
```

[Chokidar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar) config options

```
chokidar.watch('file', {
  persistent: true,

  ignored: '*.txt',
  ignoreInitial: false,
  followSymlinks: true,
  cwd: '.',
  disableGlobbing: false,

  usePolling: false,
  interval: 100,
  binaryInterval: 300,
  alwaysStat: false, // <------- turn this on
  depth: 99,
  awaitWriteFinish: {
    stabilityThreshold: 2000,
    pollInterval: 100
  },

  ignorePermissionErrors: false,
  atomic: true // or a custom 'atomicity delay', in milliseconds (default 100)
});
```

Comment: Hi! First thanks for your answer! I'm not sure if I understand your answer correctly. 
As far as I see, your code just checks if the contents of the file have changed, thus resulting in a larger size of the watched file. But I want to check, if specific contents of the file have changed, not the file as a whole. So for example if the content of a string inside the file has changed.

Comment: No, problem, @FelixRanesberger. Indeed, the stats API provides metadata about the file. It sounds like you're looking for a diff. I don't think you can do it all with one library, but you could piece it together with a few... The suggestion above about running the regex after the file change could be possible, but doesn't get you the diff.

Answer (score 0):

Chokidar does not provide a way to directly compare the contents of the file before and after the change. However, you can use it with `fs` library to detect the difference in the contents of the file.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
const util = require('util');

let previousContent = '';

chokidar.watch('file.txt', {
  ignored: /(^|[\/\\])\../,
}).on('change', (path) => {
  const content = await fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');
  const match = content.match(/regex/);
  if (match && previousContent !== match[0]) {
      console.log(`change detected: ${match[0]}`);
      previousContent = match[0];
      // run your JS function here
  }
});
```

Comment: This is close, though there are syntax errors with parentheses and braces. Also, you won't need to use async/await with `readFileSync`. Lastly, depending on the size of your files and speed of your disks you may want to properly set the `awaitWriteFinish` setting in your `watch` configuration.